# The meaning of '=' sign in nginx.conf

Tags: http, nginx, https, configuration, http-redirect

Let's assume I run a service using `nginx` on `www.example.com`. I have the whole traffic on `port:80`. `https`is required. I decided to remove the service which was on `example.com/` and move the user directly to `example.com/dir/`.

The most popular solution on StackOverflow is to add

```
location = / {
    return 301 /dir/;
}
```

Unfortunately it does forward to `http://www.example.com/dir/` instead of `https://www.example.com/dir/`. I have also tried:

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://$http_host/dir/;
}
```

and

```
location = / {
    return 301 https://$host/dir/;
}
```

but they both fail.

On the other hand, I can find:

```
location / {
    ...
}
```

in this file.

Here I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between `location = / {}` and `location / {}`?
2. Is there any configuration trick for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates. For example, if a “/” request happens frequently, defining “location = /” will speed up the processing of these requests, as search terminates right after the first comparison. Such a location cannot obviously contain nested locations.

You can find more information on the location blocks here: [Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

EDIT: as mentioned below in the comments to use HTTPS you must use the `ssl` parameter for example a server block might be:

```
server {
            listen  443     ssl;
            ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.pem

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Feel free to uparrow myquestion so it's range will increase. If it'll help me to solve the problem, I'll mark your answer as solution.

Comment: As for an answer to your 2nd question -  To configure a HTTPS server you must use the `ssl` parameter

Comment: On my current configuration, I can use https:// - maybe it's in one of the other configuration files...